# Microsoft Graph API: Search for a driveItem in a drive with name = "x"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

If I access a drive with

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!w77t6UDNUE2hgiJQ1dywCjOSaA2KClFDr4RiidIVL7B1KX2LE3mjTr2Fd5NEwAf0
```

Is it possible to find a `driveItem` file where `name = "x"`

Answer (score 1):

One option to find [`driveItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) by `name` would be to utilize the following query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/children?$filter=name eq '{file-name}'
```

Documentation: [filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter)

Another one to utilize [Search for a DriveItems within a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{file-name}')
```